# PHP within <a> tag

Tags: php, html

Can anyone see what is wrong with this line of code?

```
<li><a href='<?php base_url()."company/view" ?>'View Companies</a></li>
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 10):

Just look at the output: There is probably an `echo` and the closing `>` missing:

```
<li><a href='<?php echo base_url()."company/view" ?>'>View Companies</a></li>
```

Comment: It also doesn't print anything. He wants `<?= base_url()."company/view" ?>` or `<?php print base_url()."company/view" ?>`.

Comment: @BoltClock He modified his answer after I posted my comment, originally he only mentioned the missing `>`.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem (will accept as answer when timer allows)

Comment: You forgot to include the missing `>` after the closing `?>` Gumbo mentioned.

Comment: @roger: As I said: You are missing the closing `>` of the `A` start tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li><a href=" <?php echo base_url().'company/view'; ?>"> View Companies </a></li>
```

I guess that should do it

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a semi-colon after your php statement

Comment: No, the semicolon does not need to be there for a single statement.

Comment: Semicolons are only required to separate statements. They can be omitted if it’s the last statement in a PHP block.